# console catch close event thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, console

I have a console application which uses a `BackgroundWorker` to run an infinite loop.

I'm trying to catch the close event and do some stuff.

I used some googled solutions, and came up with the following:

```
class Program
{
   private static bool keepAlive = false;
   private static BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

   private static void runThread ()
   {
       while (keepAlive) {}
   }

   private bool ConsoleClosingCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
   {
       switch (ctrlType)
       {
           case CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
               keepAlive = false;
               break;
       }
       return true;
   }

   [DllImport("Kernel32")]
   public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

   public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

   public enum CtrlTypes
   {
       CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
       CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
       CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
       CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
       CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
   }

   public static void Start ()
   {
       keepAlive = true;
       bgWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) => runThread();
       bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

   }

   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Program p = new Program();

       SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(p.ConsoleClosingCheck), true);

       p.Start();
   }
}
```

When I debug it and close the console using the "X" (normal close) it doesn't stop at the `case`, instead the application crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you define crashing? Is there any stacktrace/message in the eventlog/debugger?

Comment: I have a try/catch block, but it doesn't stop there. Instead, I get a pop-up error with this description: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued." The output window shows multiple lines with the following message: "A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll"

Comment: Same thing is happening with my code. A backgroundWorker and a closing event, if i close the program before calling a static method inside the DoWork, everything goes ok. very strange

Answer (score 0):

The example code doesn't compile for me:

```
Member 'Program.Start()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference;
```

I suspect that the problem is just because the 'p' object that you create does not have a managed root (no managed class keeps a reference to it), there is only an unmanaged callback that refers to it.

This means that p can get garbage collected, causing a failure when calling the callback.

I tried converting the example Program class to be all static. It didn't wait in the Start() method so I added a wait on BackgroundWorker.IsBusy at the end of the start method.
I also added such a wait in the callback; otherwise, its just a race to see if the rest of the doWork method gets to execute:

```
case CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
{
    keepAlive = false;
    while (bgWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    break;
}
```